# Similar books to "High Speed Digital Design: A Handbook of Black Magic"

Tags: analog, rf, books

I am really enjoying reading this book, ["High Speed Digital Design: A Handbook of Black Magic"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133957241), in particular the more in-depth material covered than in undergrad courses and the practical approach the author takes instead of being bogged down with endless theory.

I was wondering if there were such similarly good books but in the field of say RF/Microwave circuits or say... analog design?

Answer (score 6):

There's the sequel [High Speed Signal Propagation: Advanced Black Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013084408X).

Answer (score 2):

It's getting long in the tooth, but Bob Pease's *Troubleshooting Analog Circuits* is still a very useful collection of design tips (even more so than 'troubleshooting').